# I can't figure out how to extract a string in bash

Tags: bash, sed, grep, find, cut

I am trying to make a bash script that will download a youtube page, see the latest video and find its url. I have the part to download the page except I can not figure out how to isolate the text with the url.
I have this to download the page

```
curl -s https://www.youtube.com/user/h3h3Productions/videos > YoutubePage.txt
```

which will save it to a file.
But I cannot figure out how to isolate the single part of a div.
The div is

```
<a class="yt-uix-sessionlink yt-uix-tile-link  spf-link  yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2" dir="ltr" title="Why I'm Unlisting the Leafyishere Rant" aria-describedby="description-id-877692" data-sessionlink="ei=a2lSV9zEI9PJ-wODjKuICg&amp;feature=c4-videos-u&amp;ved=CD4QvxsiEwicpteI1I3NAhXT5H4KHQPGCqEomxw" href="/watch?v=q6TNODqcHWA">Why I'm Unlisting the Leafyishere Rant</a>
```

And I need to isolate the href at the end but i cannot figure out how to do this with grep or sed.

Comment: [edit] your question to include the sample input that would produce that output (`The div is`). To paraphrase Karate Kid 3, "A man can't see, he can't parse".

Answer (score 0):

With sed :

```
sed -n 's/<a [^>]*>/\n&/g;s/.*<a.*href="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p'  YoutubePage.txt
```

To just extract the video `ahref` :

```
$ sed -n 's/<a [^>]*>/\n&/g;s/.*<a.*href="\(\/watch\?[^"]*\)".*/\1/p' YoutubePage.txt
/watch?v=q6TNODqcHWA
/watch?v=q6TNODqcHWA
/watch?v=ix4mTekl3MM
/watch?v=ix4mTekl3MM
/watch?v=fEGVOysbC8w
/watch?v=fEGVOysbC8w
...
```

To omit repeated lines :

```
$ sed -n 's/<a [^>]*>/\n&/g;s/.*<a.*href="\(\/watch\?[^"]*\)".*/\1/p' YoutubePage.txt | sort | uniq
/watch?v=2QOx7vmjV2E
/watch?v=4UNLhoePqqQ
/watch?v=5IoTGVeqwjw
/watch?v=8qwxYaZhUGA
/watch?v=AemSBOsfhc0
/watch?v=CrKkjXMYFzs
...
```

You can also pipe it to your `curl` command :

```
curl -s https://www.youtube.com/user/h3h3Productions/videos | sed -n 's/<a [^>]*>/\n&/g;s/.*<a.*href="\(\/watch\?[^"]*\)".*/\1/p' | sort | uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lynx` which is a terminal browser, but have a `-dump` mode which will output a HTML parsed text, with URL extracted. This makes it easier to grep the URL:

```
lynx -dump 'https://www.youtube.com/user/h3h3Productions/videos' \
  | sed -n '/\/watch?/s/^ *[0-9]*\. *//p'
```

This will output something like:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EBbLPnQ-CEw
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2QOx7vmjV2E
...
```

Breakdown:

```
-n '                             # Disable auto printing
    /\/watch?/                   # Match lines with /watch?
              s/^ *[0-9]*\. *//  # Remove leading index: " 123. https://..." -> 
                                 # "https://..."
                               p # Print line if all the above have not failed.
                                '
```